# Twitter4J - Get when user is tagged and reply?

Tags: java, api, twitter, streaming, twitter4j

I am making a Twitter bot that will reply whenever it's account is tagged with @accountname. The problem is that I can't find a way to do something when a user is tagged. I've looked into the Streaming API, but there were not methods relating to a user being tweeted at. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've figured it out! It seems there's a way to get user mentions using the 4J API. I'll give you the methods for those concerned:

```List<Status> statuses = twitter.getMentionsTimeline();
```

Will return a list of mentions as a Status object. Now you could just iterate over them. Enjoy !